# Singleton losing state while the application is running

Tags: android, singleton

I am trying to store data loaded from a network call in a singleton. But somehow the singleton object becomes null while the application is running.

What I have basically done is I maintain load data from network API in a singleton. The user object is set on successful login but when I access the same user object on button click it gives me a null pointer exception.
I replaced the implementation with shared preference and everything works fine.
What I dont understand is singletons persist while your running the application. How is my singleton losing state while the app process still alive?

Comment: Add some code, of your singleton.

Comment: Edit your question to include the minimum amount of code required to replicate your problem, and also supply your error stacktrace

Comment: There is no way a singleton can 'loose' it states. If it does, it could be that you are somewhere changing its state and you are unaware of it or in the worst case it's not even a singleton as you may have thought.

Comment: Im not changing the state. Because the same amount of getters and setters are still being accessed I just changed the implementation to shared preference and it works fine. If I was changing the the state, the shared preference implementation would not have worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where are you instantiating your singleton?  If in an Activity, that Activity is probably going out of scope (as it does when paused), and some of its variables are nullified.  You could try instantiating it in the Application object instead.  That never goes out of scope for the life of the app session.

Comment: Yes it is being called from multiple activities. I basically have this centric class that keeps all the singletons in a map. And i ask the class for accessing the singletons throughout the application. But like isn't the singleton alive till the time the app process is alive?

Comment: You didn't answer my question.  Where are you instantiating this singleton?  If you are doing so in your 'centric class', where is that object instantiated?  If you want something to be alive as long as the app process is alive, you need to instantiate the object in the application class, not, say, the MainActivity class.

Comment: Do you mean to say that i need to populate the map in app class?
My map has basically different singletons. Like singleton A is being accessed in app class. But like singleton B would be accessed in some activity where it is required. So like if i want singleton B to be alive throughout the app should I load it in app class?